# Volume of region bounded

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the region bounded by $y-x^3+1$, $y=0$, $x=0$ and $x=1$ revolved around the $x$-axis.

I got $\frac{9\pi}{14}$ but the actual answer was $\frac{23\pi}{14}$.

My work was to first get y by itself which made y= x^3 - 1

Then I created the equation $\int _0^1\pi \left|x^3-1\right|^2dx\:$

And when solved I get $\frac{9\pi}{14}$ which is wrong

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did you get that value?

Comment: I put it into a basic integral with squares over the formula and multiplied it by pi

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: You got a negative value?  Then I suggest you may not have applied the formula correctly.  $\pi \int_a^b \left(f(x)\right)^2\,dx$ can't be negative, if $a<b$.

Comment: it should be fixed @lulu

Comment: Still not clear.  What's $y$?  Before you said $y=x^3+1$, did you mean to say $x^3-1$?  You have written "$y-x^3+1$" which I assume is a typo.

Comment: Anyway, that's your confusion.  If we use $y=x^3+1$ as you wrote originally, we get $\frac {23}{14}\times \pi$.  If you use $y=x^3-1$, we get $\frac 9{14}\times \pi$.  Once you clear up what was intended, there should be no mystery.

Comment: @lulu one of the moderators or whatever they're called changed the subtraction to an equals sign y - x^3 +1is the proper way of writing it

Comment: No, it isn't.  That doesn't mean anything.  We need to know what curve bounds the region....$y-x^3+1$ is not a curve.  Since you claimed that $\frac {23}{14}\times \pi$ was the official answer, I expect the curve is $y=x^3+1$.

Comment: @lulu that's why I had to get y by itself, but no I see what went wrong the equals sign was misprinted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It is immediately obvious what we should do here. Washer integration(disk technically, but whatever)

Outer function is $y=x^3+1$
Inner function is $y=0$

Hence, $$V=\int_0^1\pi\left((x^3+1)^2-(0)^2\right)\text{ d}x$$
We do not need absolute values because our function is always positive on this region of integration.

We have
\begin{align*}
V&=\pi\int_0^1(x^3+1)^2-(0)^2\text{ d}x\\
&=\pi\int_0^1 x^6+2x^3+1\text{ d}x\\
&=\left.\pi\left(\frac{x^7}7+\frac{x^4}2+x\right)\right|^1_0\\
&=\pi\left[\left(\frac{1^7}7+\frac{1^4}2+1\right)-\left(\frac{0^7}7+\frac{0^4}2+0\right)\right]\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{1}7+\frac{1}2+1\right)=\frac{23\pi}{14}
\end{align*}